# Control built-in MacBook Pro Speakers with keyboard while using alternate sound output

Tags: keyboard, audio, speakers

Is there any way to control my built-in MacBook Pro Speakers with the keyboard sound controls (F10, F11, F12) while using an alternate device for sound output? I am using HDMI/DisplayPort speakers for sound output while using my built-in MacBook Pro Speakers specifically for Zoom (you can specify the output speakers in Zoom's preferences) and would like to adjust the built-in speaker's volume with the keyboard.

I've played around with eqMac and have looked at alternates like SoundFlower but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [MonitorControl](https://github.com/MonitorControl/MonitorControl#readme). It allows you to control both brightness and volume of connected external monitors and your MacBook's own facilities.

Comment: Oh that's an application I hadn't seen before, thanks for the recommendation. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to support the specific feature I'm looking for but has a lot of other great audio/keyboard features for multi-monitor setups